# Eclipse Indigo OS X arrow and backspace keys no longer work

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I'm doing some Android dev and after a number of projects I recently found my arrow and backspace keys no longer work in the editor view (Java and XML).

It works in all other apps. I've tried restarting Eclipse and restarting my macbook, but it still occurs.

Can anyone help? :(

Comment: p.s. I have tried the laptop keyboard and a usb keyboard... the same problem occurs on both.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've uninstalled an app called Air Display I had installed. Apparently it has issues with my late 2008 macbook pro on Lion (I lost the drag and drop ability).

after a reboot, all is working again.

Comment: I also had this problem, on a Late 2008 Macbook Pro, on Mountain Lion.

Deleted Air Display (it didn't work), and all working fine again.

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Keys
```

Check if you've made a strange hotkey using space or the arrows

Comment: I restored defaults in the general keys panel. Problem still occurs. :s

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a middle click in the editor and try again.